# Return different combinations of outputs depending on input

Tags: python, algorithm, function

In my functions I have a list `params_to_opt` that can include any of the following entries: `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'`, `'e'`.

Example: `params_to_opt=['c', 'e', 'a']`. It can contain any number (1 to 5) of the entries I specified. It always contains at least one of the above entries.

Depending on this input, I do various calculations:

```
def MyFunction(params_to_opt):
    if 'a' in params_to_opt:
        out1 = ...
    if 'b' in params_to_opt:
        out2= ...
    if 'c' in params_to_opt:
        out3 = ...
    if 'd' in params_to_opt:
        out4= ...
    if 'e' in params_to_opt:
        out5 = ...
```

Now I want to return only those values that were calculated. For example, if `params_to_opt=['c', 'e', 'a']`, I would return `out1`, `out3` and `out5`.

The problem is that if I was to use if .. else statement again, I would have to consider 31 possible outputs (5+10+10+5+1 depending on the length of my list).

Is there a way to code it more elegantly? I don't care about performance, as the number of outputs is very small compared to the time of calculations of each out1, out2, out3, out4, out5.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for five independent variables; just declare one list, and append to it as necessary.

```
def MyFunction(params_to_opt):
    results = []
    if 'a' in params_to_opt:
        results.append(...)
    if 'b' in params_to_opt:
        results.append(...)
    if 'c' in params_to_opt:
        results.append(...)
    if 'd' in params_to_opt:
        results.append(...)
    if 'e' in params_to_opt:
        results.append(...)
    return results
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This also returns outputs in the correct order as I needed

Comment: Since the original question mentions that calculations are performed according to different input parameters, I think the efficiency may be improved if all five calculates are preprocessed and only results are retrieved. This is even more important if multiple `params_to_opt` are queried.

Comment: @HongboZhu can you clarify? What do you mean by preprocessing?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin :  if you have multiple `params_to_opt` to query, e.g. `['a','b']`, `['a','b','c']`,`['b','c']`, the calculations corresponding to `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` will be performed 2, 3, 2 times, resp.   So it is more efficient to stored the pre-calculated results and only retrieve the restults.

Comment: Of course, this is only about the performance, which you don't care as you said in the question :)

Comment: Preprocessing the calculations can indeed improve performance, but it can only be applied in situations where the calculation would have produced the same result every time. For example, suppose you extend the OP's example so that the function takes two arguments, x and params_to_opt. If all the calculations depend on the value of x, then you can't preprocess the calculations before the function is called, because x doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. This is not the case in my real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other solution where you can avoid having multiple if statement in a row, which can become hard to maintain at certain point.

```
l = ['a', 'b']

l2 = ['a', 'c', 'e']

output = {
    'a': 'out1',
    'b': 'out2',
    'c': 'out3',
    'd': 'out4',
    'e': 'out5',
}


def MyFunction(params_to_opt):
    return [output.get(param) for param in sorted(params_to_opt)]


print(MyFunction(l), end='\n')    # ['out1', 'out2']
print(MyFunction(l2))             # ['out1', 'out3', 'out5']
```

You can put what ever you want in the dictionary: string, function, condition etc

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could also use a generator (and use a dict):

```
dictionary = {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'beta'}

def MyFunction(params_to_opt):
    for param in params_to_opt:
        if param in dictionary:
            yield dictionary[param]

result = [x for x in  MyFunction(['a', 'b'])]
```

I've used a simple a and b as input, but this can obviously be adjusted.